# Divide list of lengths into balanced chunks

Tags: python, optimization, counter

I have to wrote a script in Python.
I have a long list of integers, they are all lengths of a particular measure, there are repetitions of course. I have to find the best "intervals" to obtain balanced chunks.
An example

```
[1,2,2,5,2,4,5,4,5]
```

using Counter and ordering the result I obtain

```
[(1,1)(2,3)(3,1)(4,1)(5,3)]
```

if I need two bucket I count the number of elements (8 in this case) and than divide this number for the number of buckets (4), so I need to form bucket with about 4 element.
In my code I parse the list of tuples, summing the number of element until this number become greater than 4, so

```
(1,1) >= 4? False
(1,1) + (2,3) = 4 >=4? True, break;
```

so first interval is 1-2, than

```
(3,1) >=4? False
(3,1)+(4,1) >=4? False
(3,1)+(4,1)+(5,3) >=4? True
```

so second interval is 3-5
In my dataset I have hundred of thousand of thousand of elements, so this task (counting, sorting, parsing) is very time consuming.
Is there any way to speed up it?

Comment: Pretty sure itertools has a bucket type thing built in

Comment: please also share what your final list should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that creates contiguous buckets of roughly equal size. It makes good use of the standard lib using `collections.Counter`, `heapq.merge`, `itertools.accumulate` and `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate
from heapq import merge
from collections import Counter
from math import sin, pi
import random

# make test data a bit uneven
def mock_data(N):
    return [int(sin(2*pi*random.random())*50 + 50) for _ in range(N)]

N = 1000000

data = mock_data(N)

counts = Counter(data)
srtcnts = sorted(counts.items())

k = 7 # number of buckets

slabels, scounts = zip(*srtcnts)
# compute cumulative bin centers
bincntrs = (a - c/2 for a, c in zip(accumulate(scounts), scounts))
# mix in the optimal boundaries
split = merge(zip(bincntrs, slabels), zip(range(0, N, -(-N//k))))
# group into boundaries and stuff between boundaries;
# keep only the stuff between
res = [[v[1] for v in grp] for k, grp in groupby(split, len) if k==2]

print(res)
# show they are balanced
print([sum(counts[i] for i in chunk) for chunk in res])
```

Sample output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38], [39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94], [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
[143297, 143387, 142010, 141358, 143224, 143617, 143107]
```